# Could a system of two parabolic mirrors form a long gaussian beam from incomming solar beams?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics

[image]My question is how far a space debris is from Earth and can a Gaussian beam from parabolic mirrors positioned in geostationary orbit consisting of soloar wavelenghts controlled from Earth reach it and melt the debris?

Answer (score 0):

Do you remember the legend about Archimedes, who burned the Roman sheeps by using mirrors? It can be hardly believed, but it is not completely impossible. Let us quantify.

The diameter of the Sun that we observe is around 0.5°. Let us call it $\theta$. This angle represents the angular spread of the light.

When we collect the light with a curved mirror (or a lens), in the focal plane we have an image of the Sun. The diameter of the image is simply $f \theta$, where $f$ is the focal length, i.e. the distance from the mirror to the focal plane. The surface of the image of the Sun, i.e. the surface of the focal spot, is proportional to $f^2 \theta^2$.

On the other hand, the power collected by the mirror is proportional to the surface of the mirror, proportional to $D^2$, where $D$ is the diameter of the mirror.

We define the power density $p$ in the focal spot as the ratio between the power of the collected light and the surface of the focal spot:

$$ p = \frac{D^2}{f^2 \theta^2} $$

that we can also rewrite as:

$$ p = \left(\frac{D}{f}\right)^2 \frac{1}{\theta^2} $$

Here we see that $p$ depends on $\theta$, which is a constant (unless we go on another planet) and on $f/D$, which is the famous parameter used by experts in photography and written on the objective lenses of the cameras.

So, the temperature you reach also depends on $f/D$, the lower it is the higher is the temperature.

If you try to burn an object with a lens, you notice that the operation is successful only if $f/D$ is not much more than 2 or 3. The same must hold on larger scales. If you want to burn an object 200 km from you, you need a mirror with a diameter of some tens km at least...

Coming back to Archimedes, the operation has been repeated recently. A sheep has been burned at a distance of 50m, with an array of mirrors with a length of 70m. You see that, in this case, the ratio between the distance of the object and the size of the mirror (set) is less than 1. It is hard to believe that such a trick can be helpful during a war, but who know.

Comment: Yes, but the focal length of a parabolic mirror can be changed to any distance by changing it's radius.

Comment: I am thinking of one collecting mirror of radius of let say 6m and the tiny one of 0.2m that reemits from the other part of the focus a more intense beam which is 36/0.04 more of intensity of the collected solar beam.As higher frequencies are absorbed fast by athmosphere and lower frequencies have higher difraction remains to calculate the two factors to get a reasonable distance of the beam effectivness.

Comment: @Adrian Howerd: yes, the focal lenght can be changed. But if you increase the focal lenght, without increasing the diameter of the mirror, the temperature that you reach decreases.

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli Optics aren't my strong point but I think I get it now.

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli Consider one large mirror with a hole in the centre and the hole has radius as the radius of a second mirror that is counterposed to the large one on the other side of the focus.The large one collects the quasiparallel rays from Sun makes a focus and the smoller which is more closer to the focus recieves the radial rays from the focus and makes them again parallel but highly more intense and sends them through the central hole of the large parabolic mirror.My  thinking is that that narrow beam could travel for many kilometers.

Comment: The scheme that you propose has a focal length and a diameter. So it does not solve the problem, since the ratio $f/D$ still must be small. Remember that there is the "conservation of brilliance", so, whatever is the optical system, there is a limitation. If you do not believe me, try to give some numbers and calculate the diameter of the beam at large distance.